# How do I use regular expressions to preserve only the first symbol in a string？

Tags: python, python-re

How can I use a regular expression to preserve only the first dot (`.`) symbol in a string？
for example, I want to take this string:

```
"1.0.0.4.55.34..3"
```

and to turn it into:

```
"1.00455343"
```

Comment: I need to keep the first decimal point,like the example I gave.

Comment: I’d recommend sorting out the source data and save yourself the post-processing trouble; if possible.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example, being numbers separated by dots and keeping only the first one, you can use a regex to split the numbers by dots and then just add the first dot:

```py
import re

s = "10.0.0.4.55.34..3"
first, *rest = re.split(r"\.+", s)
print(f"{first}.{''.join(rest)}")
```

Gives:

```
10.00455343
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.But when the string is "10.0.0.4.55.34.. 3",How should I deal with it?

Comment: Why not just `first, *rest = s.split('.')` ?

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Also possible. But first OP asked for regex, second notice the double dots before the last `3`. Regular `split` is not enough to handle that case neatly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex and sub, you can use the below

```
str1 = "1.0.0.4.55.34..3"

def func(group1, group2):
    return group1 + group2.replace('.', '')

re.sub(r'(.*?\.)(.*)', lambda x : func(x.group(1), x.group(2)), str1)
'1.00455343'
```

It turns out it is slightly faster than the split -

```
%%timeit
re.sub(r'(.*?\.)(.*)', lambda x : func(x.group(1), x.group(2)), str1)
1.31 µs ± 38.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
first, *rest = re.split(r"\.+", str1)
f"{first}.{''.join(rest)}"
1.99 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```